# How to create dynamic link in jsp?

Tags: jsp

I get the list of records using `request.getAttribute()` method. After that, I show this list using `for` loop on jsp. But each record(blog) has feature as 'delete' , 'edit' . For this, I really need to generate links with path containing id of blog. That is why I need dynamic links. But I couldn't generate it. How to do that? Below is part of my code:

```
<%
    ArrayList<Blogs> blogs = (ArrayList<Blogs>) request.getAttribute("blogList");

    for (Blogs blog : blogs) {
%>
<br>
<h2>
    <%=blog.getTitle()%>
</h2>
<p>
    <%=blog.getContent()%>
</p>
<b>
    Written at : <%=blog.getPost_data().toString()%>
</b>
<br>
<!-- <a href="/delete?id=">How to pass the id to link?</a> -->
<hr>
<%
    }
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="/delete?id=<%= blog.getId()%>">
```

assuming `Blog` has a `getId()` method.

More appropriately though, you should consider using jstl `<c:forEach>` with el.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0380__JSTL/UseForEachtoLoopThroughArrayList.htm